# Is there a way to migrate *just* server settings from IIS 7 on one PC to another?

Tags: iis-7, migration

I'm not a system Admin (as evidenced by this question :).

I just need to configure my new IIS 7 client to connect to our web server. I'd like to just export the settings (but NOT the website which is now out of date on the old computer) from the old computer to a new computer.

Any pointers to good instructions on that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like msdeploy could be used here.  It's pretty powerful and seems to be my go-to tool for IIS tasks.  Maybe someone more versed in msdeploy can chime in with an exact command that would do what you want.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deploy/